# Cannot bevel above certain dimension

Tags: bevel

I cannot bevel above certain point. I have done merge by distance, remove clamping in bevel modifier. Not sure what is the problem now. There is weird artifacts appearing too.[image: Image 1]

This is how my mesh looks like
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There could be many reasons. Consider [sharing your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Have you applied the scale in Object mode?

Comment: @JachymMichal file is added. thank you!

Comment: @moonboots yes I have applied the scale too.

Comment: it looks like you didn't, it fixes the problem

Comment: @moonboots .... Ohhh! too bad from my side. I might have selected back body while checking the object props. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your scale in *Object* mode, otherwise your bevel will be distorted. Also make sure that the *Amount* value is low as your object is rather small:

[image]

Comment: yes. this resolved my issue! Thank you so much :)